# Sqlsrv_connect() error

Tags: php

I'm trying to connect PHP 5.3.5 to  MS Sql Server 2005. I'm using Windows XP SP3. I enabled the sqlsrv function which is also shown in phpinfo(). I also made some changes in the php.ini extension but I keep getting following error:

> "Database connection errorArray ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP
>   [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -49 [code] => -49 [2] => This extension
>   requires either the Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Native Client (SP1 or
>   later) or the Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Native Client ODBC Driver
>   to communicate with SQL Server. Neither of those ODBC Drivers are
>   currently installed. Access the following URL to download the
>   Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Native Client ODBC driver for x86:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 [message] => This
>   extension requires either the Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Native Client
>   (SP1 or later) or the Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Native Client ODBC
>   Driver to communicate with SQL Server. Neither of those ODBC Drivers
>   are currently installed. Access the following URL to download the
>   Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Native Client ODBC driver for x86:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 ) [1] => Array ( [0] =>
>   IM002 [SQLSTATE] => IM002 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC
>   Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver
>   specified [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source
>   name not found and no default driver specified ) ) 1"

I've installed `sqlncli.msi` , `SQLSRV20.exe` and `SQLSRV30.exe` but I'm still getting the same error.

My program to connect:

```
<?php
$server = "Patrik/SQLEXPRESS";
$conInfo = array("Database"=>"ShoppingDetail","UID"=>"Pat1890","PWD"=>"Pat1890");

$con = sqlsrv_connect($server,$conInfo);

if($con==false)
 {
  echo "Error Connecting to database<br>";
   die (print_r(sqlsrv_errors()));
  }
else
{
  echo "Database connection is sucessfully eastablished";
}
?>
```

I think there is no problem in my coding. I also enabled TCP/IP and used the IP address instead of servername but the problem still persists.

Answer (score 1):

Fisrt verify, in php.ini

> extension=php_pdo_mssql.dll

and

> extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll

and try with PDO

```
$server = 'host';
$database = 'database';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$db = new PDO('odbc:Driver={SQL Server}; Server=' . $server . '; Database=' . $database . '; Uid=' . $username . '; Pwd=' . $password . ';');
$query = $db->prepare('...');
$query->execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

To use the `sqlsrv_*` functions, add `extension=php_sqlsrv_X_Y.dll` to your php.ini, where `X` represents your PHP version (`53` in your case) and `Y` is either `ts` or `nts` for whether you installed the thread-safe/non-thread-safe build of PHP. Those DLLs should all be in your PHP install's `ext` folder.